# how to distribute the .ipa files to the TestFlight using fastlane

Tags: xcode, testflight, fastlane

I have .ipa file which I generated using Xcode utility, so now I want to upload this .ipa files in to the TestFlight using fastlane, can anyone help me the steps on this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make sure that the bundle identifier exists both on Apple Developer Center (to sign the app) and in App Store Connect (to push the app to the store).

Than you just need to implement [Pilot](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/) which is Fastlane action to push ipa files to Testflight.

Comment: is testflight provides any api-key for pushing the ipa files to testflight??

Comment: No, App Store Connect (the service behind Testflight) doesn't work with api key. You need to use the credentials you use to login to the web panel (or you can create dedicated credentials). Fastlane, then, stores these credentials in the keychain. See credentials manager https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/credentials_manager